# How do I increase the number of partitions when I read in a hive table in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hivecontext

So, I am trying to read in a hive table in Spark with hiveContext.
The job basically reads data from two tables into two Dataframes which are subsequently converted to RDD's. I, then, join them based on a common key.
However, this join is failing due to a MetadataFetchFailException ([What are the likely causes of org.apache.spark.shuffle.MetadataFetchFailedException: Missing an output location for shuffle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29850784/what-are-the-likely-causes-of-org-apache-spark-shuffle-metadatafetchfailedexcept)).

I want to avoid that by spreading my data over to other nodes.
Currently, even though I have 800 executors, most data is being read into 10 nodes, each of which is using > 50% of its memory.

The question, is, how do I spread the data over to more partitions during the read operation? I do not want to repartition later on.

```
 val tableDF= hiveContext.read.table("tableName")
                         .select("colId1", "colId2")
                         .rdd
                         .flatMap(sqlRow =>{
                            Array((colId1, colId2))
                         })
```